# Multi GPU/Tower setup Tensorflow 1.2 Estimator

Tags: python, tensorflow, multi-gpu

I want to turn my `_model_fn` for `Estimator` into a multi GPU solution.

Is there a way to do it within the Esitmator API or do I have to explicitly code device placement and synchronization.

I know I can use `tf.device('gpu:X')` to place my model on GPU `X`. I also know I can loop over available GPU names to replicate my model across multiple GPUs. I also know I can use a single input queue for multiple GPUs.

What I do not know is which parts (optimizer, loss calculation), I can actually move to a GPU and where I have to synchronize the computation.

From the `Cifar10` example I figure that I have to only synchronize the gradient.

Especially when using

```
train_op = tf.contrib.layers.optimize_loss(
        loss=loss,
        global_step=tf.contrib.framework.get_global_step(),
        learning_rate=learning_rate,
        learning_rate_decay_fn=_learning_rate_decay_fn,
        optimizer=optimizer)
```

I cannot call `optimizer.compute_gradients()` or `optimizer.apply_gradients()` manually anymore as this is internally handled by `.optimize_loss(..)`

I am wondering how to average the gradients like it is done in the *cifar10* example [Cifar10-MultiGPU](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/6936918ad8abd7ade445674d7c912e69157a1017/tensorflow/models/image/cifar10/cifar10_multi_gpu_train.py#L178) or if this is even the right approach for `Estimator`.

Answer (score 4):

Actually you can implement multi GPU in model_fn function same as before.
You can find full code in [here](https://github.com/BobLiu20/Classification_Nets/blob/master/tensorflow/training/train_estimator.py). It is support multi threading queue reader and multi GPU to very high speed training when using estimator.

Code snippet: ([GET FULL CODE](https://github.com/BobLiu20/Classification_Nets/blob/master/tensorflow/training/train_estimator.py))

```
def model_fn(features, labels, mode, params):
    # network
    network_fn = nets_factory.get_network_fn(
        FLAGS.model_name,
        num_classes=params['num_classes'],
        weight_decay=0.00004,
        is_training=(mode == tf.estimator.ModeKeys.TRAIN))

    # if predict. Provide an estimator spec for `ModeKeys.PREDICT`.
    if mode == tf.estimator.ModeKeys.PREDICT:
        logits, end_points = network_fn(features)
        return tf.estimator.EstimatorSpec(mode=mode, predictions={"output": logits})

    # Create global_step and lr
    global_step = tf.train.get_global_step()
    learning_rate = get_learning_rate("exponential", FLAGS.base_lr,
                                      global_step, decay_steps=10000)

    # Create optimizer
    optimizer = get_optimizer(FLAGS.optimizer, learning_rate)

    # Multi GPU support - need to make sure that the splits sum up to 
    # the batch size (in case the batch size is not divisible by 
    # the number of gpus. This code will put remaining samples in the
    # last gpu. E.g. for a batch size of 15 with 2 gpus, the splits 
    # will be [7, 8].
    batch_size = tf.shape(features)[0]
    split_size = batch_size // len(params['gpus_list'])
    splits = [split_size, ] * (len(params['gpus_list']) - 1)
    splits.append(batch_size - split_size * (len(params['gpus_list']) - 1))

    # Split the features and labels
    features_split = tf.split(features, splits, axis=0)
    labels_split = tf.split(labels, splits, axis=0)
    tower_grads = []
    eval_logits = []

    with tf.variable_scope(tf.get_variable_scope()):
        for i in xrange(len(params['gpus_list'])):
            with tf.device('/gpu:%d' % i):
                with tf.name_scope('%s_%d' % ("classification", i)) as scope:
                    # model and loss
                    logits, end_points = network_fn(features_split[i])
                    tf.losses.softmax_cross_entropy(labels_split[i], logits)
                    update_ops = tf.get_collection(
                        tf.GraphKeys.UPDATE_OPS, scope)
                    updates_op = tf.group(*update_ops)
                    with tf.control_dependencies([updates_op]):
                        losses = tf.get_collection(tf.GraphKeys.LOSSES, scope)
                        total_loss = tf.add_n(losses, name='total_loss')
                    # reuse var
                    tf.get_variable_scope().reuse_variables()
                    # grad compute
                    grads = optimizer.compute_gradients(total_loss)
                    tower_grads.append(grads)
                    # for eval metric ops
                    eval_logits.append(logits)

    # We must calculate the mean of each gradient. Note that this is the
    # synchronization point across all towers.
    grads = average_gradients(tower_grads)

    # Apply the gradients to adjust the shared variables.
    apply_gradient_op = optimizer.apply_gradients(
        grads, global_step=global_step)

    # Track the moving averages of all trainable variables.
    variable_averages = tf.train.ExponentialMovingAverage(0.9999, global_step)
    variables_averages_op = variable_averages.apply(tf.trainable_variables())

    # Group all updates to into a single train op.
    train_op = tf.group(apply_gradient_op, variables_averages_op)

    # Create eval metric ops
    _predictions = tf.argmax(tf.concat(eval_logits, 0), 1)
    _labels = tf.argmax(labels, 1)
    eval_metric_ops = {
        "acc": slim.metrics.streaming_accuracy(_predictions, _labels)}

    # Provide an estimator spec for `ModeKeys.EVAL` and `ModeKeys.TRAIN` modes.
    return tf.estimator.EstimatorSpec(
        mode=mode,
        loss=total_loss,
        train_op=train_op,
        eval_metric_ops=eval_metric_ops)
```